# Tangent space of the tangent bundle

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a differential $k-$manifold in $\mathbb R^n$, $g:TM\rightarrow\mathbb R$ given by $g(x,v)=|v|^2$, where $|\cdot|$ is the usual norm in $\mathbb R^n$. Show that $Reg(g)=Reg(g_{\partial TM})=\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$.

I know that if $\pi:TM\rightarrow M$ is the projection $\pi(x,v)=x$, then $\partial TM=\pi^{-1}(\partial M)$.

I tried this:

Let $(x,v)\in TM$, then

$dg_{(x,v)}:T_{(x,v)}TM\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is such that if $w=(w_1,...,w_k,w_{k+1},...,w_{2k})\in T_{(x,v)}TM$

$dg_{(x,v)}(w)=2(v_1w_{k+1}+...+v_kw_{2k})$.

As $g:TM\rightarrow\mathbb R$, then $dg_{(x,v)}$ is surjective iff $dg_{(x,v)}\neq 0$, for all $(x,v)\in TM$.

**First edited version:**

Using the definition of $dg_{(x,v)}$, it is surjective, iff $v\neq 0$ ...(1)

Let $y\in Reg(g)$, then if $(x,v)\in g^{-1}(y)$ we have

1. $g(x,v)=y$, i.e., $v_1^2+...+v_k^2=y$.
2. $dg_{(x,v)}$ is surjective and by (1) $v\neq 0$. Then $y\neq 0$.

Comment: Well...is $dg_{(x,0)}$ surjective?

Comment: Thanks, i have edited it, and for the part of the boundary? 

I am confused, because i havent used "x" anywhere and it will be the same.